# How to reuse React component that has different markup?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component today, which represents a container box that has a heading and different rows. This is how it looks:

```
var Box = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <BoxHeading title={this.props.headingTitle}/>
      <BoxBody rows={this.props.rows} />
    )
  }
});

var BoxBody = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      {this.rows()}
    )
  }

  rows: function() {
    return _.map(this.props.rows, function(row) {
      return (
        <HouseRow />
      );
    }, this);
  }
});
```

Now my question is: If I want to reuse the Box & BoxBody but instead of using  I want to use another kind of Row, how would I do it?

Would I pass the kind of component that I want as row to the Box?

So, I would do `<Box rowType={<HouseRow} />` or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you chose looks really good — you can basically combine Box with every type of row you want, provided it has a correct interface. It is called [Object Composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) and is a legit and well respected pattern in software engineering.

The only thing is, in React you should do it not by passing a already rendered component, but the component class, like this:

```
<Box rowComponent={ HouseRow } />
```

As you see, you don't need to use parenthesis. And inside component, you do something like this:

```
var RowComponent = this.props.rowComponent;
return (
   <RowComponent />
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, how do you deal with the fact than different types of `rowComponents` might expect different props? Like one might expect a prop called `picture` but another one might expect a prop named `title`. Do you pass the props that will be used in the row component as an Object literal?

Comment: In your case I would pass all the row data to the component via JSX spread attributes and let the row component decide for itself which props it wants to use https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<Box rowType={HouseRow} />
```

This is exactly how you would do it. Pass dynamic content that varies from components as props from a parent. Then in your rows function, `return <{@props.rowType} />` should work